# Failing to build application when deploying website on cloudflare pages

Tags: github, web, static, cloudflare, deploying

I have been trying to deploy my portfolio website on cloudflare pages .But its ends up failing to the build application. I cant find solution online please  help. Error pointed with the red mark in the picture

[image]

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs? Any error message?

Comment: No i cant see any errors in the log

Comment: Then it will not be easy for any of us to guess what went wrong, without a bit more detail about the kind of application being build.